# Is there a command that gives the page numbers of an index entry?

Tags: indexing, imakeidx, makeindex, page

Is there a command---for example, something like `\pages{pangolins}`--- that represents the page numbers (and page ranges) of an index entry "pangolins"?  If not, is there any elegant way to code such a command, with or without the use of existing index packages like imakeidx?

Here is a minimal example of how such a command could be used:

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{imakeidx}
\makeindex

\begin{document}

Here is a paragraph about pangolins\index{pangolins}.  Pangolins are the only mammals covered in scales.

Here is a paragraph about meerkats.  Meerkats are immune to the venom of scorpions and snakes.

Here is another paragraph about pangolins.  A single pangolin can consume 20,000 ants per day.  If you want to learn more about pangolins, see page \pages{pangolins}.

\end{document}
```

Comment: I don't know of any such instruction, but the index entries with page numbers are written out (in order of occurrence) to an `.idx` file.  It should be possible to read these in, look for the desired entry (it can occur multiple times), and collect the page numbers recorded there.

Comment: Interesting idea, though it sounds above my current skill level in LaTeX.  Does anyone have a code example?

Comment: Let me add that, for my application, it would be fine to assume that there is only a single, simple \index command per index entry -- just one `\index{panolins}`, `\index{meerkats}`, etc. in the text, and no page ranges, subentries, cross-referencing, or similar complexity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This supports also page ranges and also multiple pages (but page ranges should not mix with single references). It uses Barbara Beeton's idea in comments to the question.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{imakeidx}
\usepackage{xparse}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\readindex}{O{\c_sys_jobname_str}}
 {
  \group_begin:
  \cs_set_eq:NN \indexentry \readindexentry
  \file_if_exist_input:n { #1.idx }
  \group_end:
 }

\NewDocumentCommand{\pages}{m}
 {
  \prop_item:Nn \g_readindex_prop { #1 }
 }

\NewDocumentCommand{\readindexentry}{>{\SplitArgument{1}{|}}m m}
 {
  \readindex_process:nnn #1 { #2 }
 }

\prop_new:N \g_readindex_prop

\cs_new_protected:Nn \readindex_process:nnn
 {
  \str_case:nnF { #2 }
   {
    { ( }{ \readindex_start:nn { #1 } { #3 } }
    { ) }{ \readindex_end:nn   { #1 } { #3 } }
   }
   { \readindex_standard:nn { #1 } { #3 } }
 }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \readindex_standard:nn
 {
  \prop_if_in:NnTF \g_readindex_prop { #1 }
   {
    \prop_gput:Nnx \g_readindex_prop { #1 }
     { \prop_item:Nn \g_readindex_prop { #1 } , ~ #2 }
   }
   {
    \prop_gput:Nnn \g_readindex_prop { #1 } { #2 }
   }
 }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \readindex_start:nn
 {
  \prop_gput:Nnn \g_readindex_prop { #1 } { #2 }
 }
\cs_new_protected:Nn \readindex_end:nn
 {
  \prop_gput:Nnx \g_readindex_prop { #1 }
   { \prop_item:Nn \g_readindex_prop { #1 } -- #2 }
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\readindex
\makeindex % must be ***after*** \readindex

\begin{document}

For elephants, see \pages{elephants}.

Here we also talk about unicorns\index{unicorns}, treated on \pages{unicorns}.

Here is a paragraph about pangolins\index{pangolins}.  
Pangolins are the only mammals covered in scales.

Here is a paragraph about meerkats.  Meerkats are immune to 
the venom of scorpions and snakes.

Here is another paragraph about pangolins.  A single pangolin 
can consume 20,000 ants per day.  If you want to learn more about 
pangolins, see page \pages{pangolins}.

Now we talk about elephants\index{elephants|(}
\lipsum[1-10]
End of elephant talk\index{elephants|)}.

Again a unicorn\index{unicorns}.

\end{document}
```

[image]

One could add automatic “page”-“pages” prefixes based on the value stored in the property list.

Multiple indices are supported, but a specific `\readindex` command should be used for each: `\readindex[<index name>]`, where the name is the file name for the corresponding `.idx` file.

Answer (score 4):

Given the rather *precise* promises you make (only one index entry per item, only one page reference etc) you could just alter the `\index` command so that it automatically creates a label with the same name as well. Then you just use the ordinary `\pageref` command to cross-reference it.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{makeidx}

\makeatletter
\def\@wrindex#1{%
\protected@write\@indexfile{}%
{\string\indexentry{#1}{\thepage}}%
\protected@write\@auxout{}%
{\string\newlabel{#1}{{\@currentlabel}{\thepage}}}%
\endgroup
\@esphack}
\makeatother

\makeindex

\begin{document}


If \index{pangolins} are referred to here, we can wait a little while and then

\clearpage


Refer to the place (\pageref{pangolins}) where we previously referred to them!

\printindex

\end{document}
```

Comment: It would probably be a good idea to insert an anchor point so that a hyperlink would be a little more localized than just access the page; however, that wasn't part of the question.

Comment: Note that hyperrref redefines both \@wrindex and \newlabel.

Answer (score 0):

And just to round out the answers, a simplistic method that came up in trying various options was to label particular words using `\phantomsection` and `\label` and then to use `\pageref` to place the page number where needed:

```
\documentclass{book}

\newcommand{\ps}{\phantomsection}

\begin{document}

Here is a paragraph about {\ps}pangolins\label{pangolins}.

Here is another paragraph about pangolins.  If you want to learn more about pangolins, see page \pageref{pangolins}.

\end{document}
```

This appeared to work in the cases I tried, but I have a limited understanding of what is going on behind the scenes in LaTeX; this approach may be flawed in ways that I haven't appreciated.  (Critiques encouraged.)

Comment: All you need is \refstepcounter for some counter to set up \label.